# Get values froma a Dataset<Row> into a .txt file (using Java)

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata, apache-spark-dataset

Im new here so i hope to help you and be helped if could be possible.

I made a Apache Spark project using Spark SQL and ML Spark in Java. I've finished this project but i have some problems with the output.

I've got a `Dataset<Row>` final (final is the name of the dataset) with some information. When i use `show()` with this dataset ( `finals.show();` ) I get the next information:

```
    [2018026,1,9.93,127.66,5.16,245.8,4.426875,6.91]
    [2018026,1,9.97,127.89,5.36,244.8,4.426875,6.91]
    [2018026,1,6.76,113.54,6.42,228.8,4.426875,6.91]
    [2018026,1,6.92,114.2,6.81,224.0,4.426875,6.91]
    [2018026,1,6.86,113.98,6.65,226.0,4.426875,6.91]
    [2018026,1,6.81,113.76,6.58,227.4,4.426875,6.91]
    [2018026,1,6.97,113.49,6.58,225.8,4.426875,6.91]
    [2018026,1,6.97,114.42,6.67,221.6,4.426875,6.91]
```

(The "," is the separator between the fields).
Well, I'm trying to get this output in text file, for example projectSpark.txt but is impossible to me. How can I get this info on a text file?
Should I iterate over the `Dataset<Row>` or are there some methods to do this?

Thank so much guys.

Regards.

Comment: Looks like CSV format, dataset.write.csv can be used.

Comment: A `DataSet` has a `toDF` method, which converts it to a generic dataframe. 
After that, as others said, it is easy to write a `DataFrame` to a file, see an example here: https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/46772/how-to-save-dataframe-as-text-file.html

Comment: @ÁlvaroValencia could be but i have never used Scala. I've tried to convert the Dataset<row> to a RDD but dont know how to get the data from the rdd to the output.

Comment: @pasha701 yes, i can convert to a CSV easily but i dont want to convert into a CSV. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @agiro i've convert other dataset into a CSV file, but this time i dont want to convert into a CSV file. I just wanto to get the values from the dataset<row> and put this data into a .txt file.

Comment: @CCantona Java and Scala are so similar. Based on the answer I have prevously specify, it would be something like that:  `finals.javaRDD().map(x -> x.toString()).saveAsTextFile("your/path");`

Comment: @ÁlvaroValencia could be something like this, but with this method i get 200 files, 180 of 200 maybe empty. Is there some method to get all the information in only one file?

Comment: @CCantona yes just use `coalesce(1)` to repartition in a single partition: `finals.javaRDD().map(x -> x.toString()).coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("your/path");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, you can do something like it:

```
finals.javaRDD().map(x -> x.toString()).saveAsTextFile("your/path");
```

It will save your dataset in a single text file.

Comment: Thank so much Álvaro. This solve my problem. Muchas gracias ;) .